# Exporting graphics to PDF results in destroyed fonts on Windows 8

Tags: export, fonts, pdf-format, windows

Executing

```
plot = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 100}, PlotLabel -> "Plot"];
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Export["plot.pdf", plot, "PDF"];
```

results in

[image: Distorted fonts]

Is this a bug? OS is Windows 8, 64bit.

Comment: There's no problem with your code - the exported PDF is fine here (MacOS X 10.8, Mathematica versions 8 and 9). Perhaps it's a problem with some of your fonts, or stylesheet, or something in your OS. It's a hard problem to solve, even with more information...

Comment: I think it's a problem of Windows 8. Can someone confirm this issue on Windows 8?

Comment: I have no problem viewing it in either Windows 8 or Windows 8.1. v9.0.1